# 12 samples, split into 2, 68 variables measured; 68 paired T-tests?

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I collected blood samples from 12 patients. Each sample was split into two different storage vessel (24 total aliquots). All 24 aliquots were analyzed for 68 elements. Since the patients are selected at random we expect to see considerable differences in some element concentrations between individuals (i.e. Cobalt can differ by as much as 80% between two different patients)

We suspect that the type of storage vessel may influence the analytical results for some of the 68 elements. I don't think I can look at the pooled variance since I only have 2 observations per element.

Is the best approach a 12 separate paired t-test (vessel 1 paired with vessel 2) for each of the 68 elements?

Comment: Should be 68 paired t-test. Maybe some of 68 elements are effected by storage vessel, and some are not.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. And yes, as it turns out there were some elements that differed, but thankfully many did not :)